# Error missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property

Tags: typescript, angular5

I am getting the problem in an angular5 application is when I am going to use "ngbuild" command then the below error is showing

E:\finalAngularapp12-6-enter code here18\althingapp\src\app\components\fabrics\Workflow\workflow.module.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.

but when I saved any HTML page any component that error got disappeared(not displaying).

Below is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
  "src/**/*.ts"
  ]
}

And below is my package.json
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "5.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "5.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "@turf/inside": "^5.0.0",
    "@turf/turf": "^5.0.4",
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.43",
    "@types/file-saver": "^1.3.0",
    "@types/geojson": "^1.0.6",
    "@types/loader-utils": "^1.1.3",
    "@types/openlayers": "^4.3.6",
    "@types/simplebar": "^2.4.1",
    "@types/tapable": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.3",
    "acorn-dynamic-import": "^3.0.0",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.3.2",
    "angular-io-slimscroll": "^2.3.3",
    "angular-router-loader": "0.8.2",
    "angular2-infinite-scroll": "^0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.4.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "bpmn-js": "^0.30.0",
    "bpmn-js-properties-panel": "^0.22.1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.16",
    "compodoc": "0.0.41",
    "constants": "0.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.7",
    "d3": "^4.12.0",
    "date-fns": "^1.29.0",
    "domain": "0.0.1",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.12",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "1.1.6",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.3",
    "geojson2shape": "^0.2.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "html-loader": "0.5.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "ie-shim": "0.1.0",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.7",
    "json-logic-js": "^1.2.2",
    "jspdf": "^1.4.0",
    "kurento-utils": "^6.6.3",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "loader-utils": "^1.0.2",
    "microsoft-applicationinsights-angular5": "^0.1.6",
    "module-exports": "^1.0.0",
    "ng-drag-drop": "^4.0.0",
    "ng2-dnd": "^4.2.0",
    "ng2draggable": "^1.3.2",
    "ng4-click-outside": "^1.0.1",
    "ngx-color-picker": "5.3.8",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^1.0.10",
    "ngx-file-drop": "3.0.0",
    "ngx-scroll-event": "^1.0.8",
    "node": "^10.2.0",
    "node-require": "0.0.10",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "npm-sass": "^2.2.1",
    "papaparse": "^4.3.7",
    "preboot": "6.0.0-beta.1",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rebuild": "^0.1.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "require": "^2.4.20",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "sass": "^1.3.2",
    "shp-write": "^0.3.2",
    "shpjs": "^3.4.2",
    "simplebar": "^2.6.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.1",
    "style-loader": "0.19.1",
    "svg-loader": "0.0.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "ts-xlsx": "0.0.11",
    "turf": "^3.0.14",
    "url-loader": "0.6.2",
    "videogular2": "^6.0.6",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^10.1.2",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "2.0.0",
    "typescript": "2.6.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "4.1.0",
    "tslint": "5.9.1"
  }
```

and

```
node-v:8.9.4
angular-cli:6.0.8
```